# unchecked -keyword in C#

Tags: c#, unchecked-conversion

Maybe I'm in the basics, but I'm still studying this C# thing at school. I understand that if I add 1 to max valued Integer, which one is 32 bit, the result will be negative. I read that C# offers checked and unchecked keywords for handling overflows. Checked keyword is something, I've found useful, but how about unchecked keyword? I really can't find not much useful use for unchecked -keyworded block. Is there any? How does the next two approaches differs from each others?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Practice_6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int value = Int32.MaxValue;
            value++;
            //Approach 1 to make a decision
            if (value > Int32.MaxValue) {
                //Do something
            }
            value = Int32.MaxValue;
            //Approach 2 to make a decision
            unchecked {
                value++;
                //Do something
            }
            //What's the difference between these two approaches to handle overflow?
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (value > Int32.MaxValue)` --- would this condition be true for some `integer` value?

Comment: Custom `GetHashCode` implementations are good examples of scenarios where `unchecked` can be useful, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1644813

Comment: if (value > INT32.MaxValue) returs True, I think

Comment: @Jere_Sumell: what if you check your assumptions first? It would take a second to do that: http://ideone.com/lEioPS

Answer (score 56):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in April 2015](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/09/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-one/); thanks for the interesting question!

---

Your first question is:

> The `checked` keyword is useful, but how about the `unchecked` keyword? I really can't find a use for it. Is there any?

The C# design team is not in the habit of adding features that have no use to the language. (With the notable exception of the unary plus operator, the world's most useless operator.)

The unchecked keyword has two main use cases.

First, *constant integer arithmetic is always checked by default*.  This can be irritating. Suppose for example you have some interop code and you wish to create a constant for the HRESULT E_FAIL:

```
const int E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
```

That's an error because that number is too big to fit into an `int`. But you might not want to use a `uint`. You might think well I'll just say

```
const int E_FAIL = (int)0x80004005;
```

But that is also illegal because constant arithmetic *including conversions* is always checked by default.

What you have to do is turn off checked constant arithmetic via

```
const int E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
```

Second, the default arithmetic for non-constant integer math in C# is unchecked, because it is faster, and because that is what many other similar languages do. However C# allows you to change the default to checked arithmetic for non-constant integer math via a compiler flag. If you've done so, and you need to turn it back off again on a temporary basis, then you have to use the `unchecked` block or expression syntax.

A third use case is to use the unchecked block as a form of self-documenting code, to say "I am aware that the operation I'm doing here might overflow, and that's fine with me."  For example, I'll often write something like:

```
int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked 
    {
        int fooCode = this.foo == null ? 0 : this.foo.GetHashCode();
        int barCode = this.bar == null ? 0 : this.bar.GetHashCode();
        return fooCode + 17 * barCode;
    }
}
```

The "unchecked" emphasizes to the reader that we fully expect that multiplying and adding hash codes could overflow, and that this is OK.

Your second question is:

> What's the difference between these two approaches to handle overflow?

Good question.

If in your checked context you mean: **I expect arithmetic to always be within bounds; if it is not then my program has a serious bug and must be terminated before it does more harm to the world** then you should not do any overflow checking at all, because there are no overflows. Any exception should terminate the program; the checked context is simply making the runtime do work to verify the correctness of your code.

If in your checked context you mean **I require arithmetic to be within bounds but I obtained this data from an untrustworthy source and I am too lazy to do range checking on it** then you should catch the exception.  *However*, the better practice would be to do range checking and give a more meaningful error if the data is out of range, than to have the runtime notice the problem and throw an overflow exception.  I would strongly recommend range checking rather than catching an exception; don't be lazy.

Comment: My preference with `unchecked` would be to focus it as narrowly as possible (just the last expression). Is there any particular reason to favor a larger scope? Also, if one is e.g. accepting data from a binary file which e.g. contains a mixture of base- and relative values, what would code be expected to do if the sum of a relative value and the base overflow? If the most plausible scenario where that would occur would that someone tried to load a file of the wrong type (implying that the file and any data read thus far should be considered meaningless, but the system is otherwise fine)...

Comment: ...what are the practical differences between throwing an exception other than OverflowException, catching OverflowException and throwing something else, throwing OverflowException and expecting the caller to assume that OverflowException implies an attempt to load something that was not a valid file of the expected type, or letting an OverflowException happen (with the same expectation re the caller)?

Comment: +1 for mentioning uselessness of the unary plus operator

Comment: @supercat: I don't have strong opinions about your first point. Sure, narrowly scoping it seems reasonable, but this is a three-line method we're talking about. Let's say that if the entire block easily appears on my screen then I'm not going to stress about whether it can be made smaller.

Comment: @supercat: Regarding binary files: I would consider whether it is *exceptional* or not to read in a corrupted or wrong file; if it is then I would catch and then throw a meaningful "file corrupted" exception. There can be serious security implications when deserializing data structures from untrusted sources; a detailed discussion of good security practices for deserialization is beyond the scope of this comment. (Many years ago I wrote a short chapter of a book on that topic, but it is long out of print.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not quite sure about performance implications of `checked` and `unchecked`. In theory, `unchecked` should be more performant and it is the default context. Unless you hang around the boundaries of integer types for some kind of special algorithm/business logic etc., using `checked` is rarely necessary/useful/readable.

As I said, `unchecked` is the default context so why do you need an `unchecked` keyword? One thing could be to be explicit about the type of a context where there's a high usage of `checked` contexts. The other is to use `unchecked` context inside `checked` context:

```
checked {
    int a = 5 + 1231;

    unchecked {
        a += 221;
    }
}
```

Your question might be why the default context is unchecked. I guess it's a design choice by Microsoft.

Their difference is that `checked` context checks if there is an overflow for each arithmetic operation and raises an exception if there is an overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Properly-written code should not be expected to depend upon whether a project is compiled with checked or unchecked as the default.  Code in which unexpecting wrapping arithmetic behavior could a risk to security or system stability should done in a `checked` context.  Code which relies upon wrapping arithmetic behavior should be done in an `unchecked` context.  General-purpose code in which arithmetic overflows are not expected to occur, but would have limited consequences if they did, should be compiled using the project-level setting.  The project level setting may then be set to checked or unchecked as a trade-off between execution speed and timely error trapping.

If no unexpected overflows are occurring anywhere, code will run faster in unchecked mode.  If, however, some computations are yielding bogus values and it's unclear why, recompiling with overflow checking enabled may help.  It will cause code to run more slowly, but will trap at the first erroneous computation.  Switching the project to checked mode for such a purpose, however, will only be possible if those portions of the project which rely upon wrapping arithmetic behavior are performed in an explicit `unchecked` context.  Otherwise switching project-level modes will simply break the program entirely.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN the reason for using unchecked would be as follows

> Because checking for overflow takes time, the use of unchecked code in situations where there is no danger of overflow might improve performance. However, if overflow is a possibility, a checked environment should be used.

Comment: While the quoted info might be useful in a way, I think OP asked about when `unchecked` keyword is useful because default context is already `unchecked`, and this doesn't answer the question

Comment: It's not necessarily the default if /checked is used, usually but not in every case

Answer (score 1):

Change your codes to:

```
  int value = int.MaxValue;
  unchecked
  {
    value++;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(value);
  value = int.MaxValue;
  checked
  {
    value++; // this will raise OverflowException
  }
```

and you will see the difference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about difference between *using `unchecked`* and *not using any keyword*

Comment: _not using any keyword_ could be similar to _using checked_ or _using unchecked_, depending on the compiler settings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx